# An $n$-dimensional generalized Hoffman’s circulation theorem?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, linear-programming, combinatorial-optimization, network-theory

For a directed graph $G$, a 1-dimensional circulation is a function $f:E(G)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for every $v\in V(G)$,
$$\sum_{uv\in E(G)}f(uv)=\sum_{vw\in E(G)}f(vw),$$
where $uv$ is an abbreviation of $(u,v)$.

Furthermore, given $\ell,c:E(G)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such $\ell(uv)\le c(uv)$ for all $uv\in E(G)$, then [Hoffman's circulation theorem](https://www.sfu.ca/%7Emdevos/notes/misc/hof-circ.pdf) gives an equivalent condition for the existence of a circulation $f$ satisfying $\ell\le f\le c$.

As a generalization, we define an $n$-dimensional circulation as a function $f:E(G)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that for every $v\in V(G)$,
$$\sum_{uv\in E(G)}f(uv)=\sum_{vw\in E(G)}f(vw).$$
Let $\pi_i$ be the projection from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to the $i$th coordinate.

Let $E_1\cup E_2=E(G)$ be a partition of the edge set of $G$.
Let $\ell,c:E(G)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $\ell(uv)\le c(uv)$ for all $uv\in E(G)$.
Assume we want an $n$-dimentional circulation $f$ satisfying for each $uv\in E_1$,

$$\ell(uv)\le \sum_{i\in [n]}\pi_i(f(uv))\le c(uv)$$

and for each $uv\in E_2$,

$$\ell(uv)\le \pi_i(f(uv))\le c(uv) \text{ for some } i\in [n].$$
Then is there any equivalent (or sufficient) condition for the existence of such $n$-dimensional circulation $f$?